# Getting Socket options from ZMQ in Node.JS binding

Tags: node.js, sockets, zeromq

I'm working with the ZMQ binding for Node.js and apparently I cannot access the options of the socket. Here's how I create sockets for `PULL` and `PUSH`:

```
var sender = zmq.socket('push');
var receiver = zmq.socket('pull');
```

Then it's quite easy to setup a messaging system, but I would like to access `_ioevents` but it's kind of hard to understand how can I access that option through the socket itself. My aim is to get to the `ZMQ_POLLIN` and `ZMQ_POLLOUT` statuses described [here](http://api.zeromq.org/master%3azmq-getsockopt#toc21). 
The content of the `PULL` socket is the following:

```
{ type: 'pull',
  _zmq: { state: 0, onReady: [Function] },
  _outgoing: [],
  _shouldFlush: true,
  _events: { message: [Function], EINTR: [Function] } }
```

Which is of no help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I was asking the wrong object the question. The object containing the `ZMQ_POLLIN` and `ZMQ_POLLOUT` statuses is `zmq` created through `var zmq = require('zmq');` which was used to create the `sender` and `receiver` objects.

By simply doing `zmq.ZMQ_POLLIN` I could access the flags. I still have to figure out what their mean is though.